# Bash tries to execute commands in heredoc

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, heredoc

I am trying to write a simple bash script that will print a multiline output to another file. I am doing it through `heredoc` format:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello!"
cat <<EOF > ~/Desktop/what.txt
a=`echo $1 | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
b=`echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
EOF
```

I was expecting to see a file in my desktop with these contents:

```
a=`echo $1 | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
b=`echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

But instead, I am seeing these as the contents of my `what.txt` file:

```
a=
b=
```

Somehow, even though it is part of a `heredoc`, bash is trying to execute it line by line. How do I prevent this, and print the contents to the file as it is?

Comment: Replace `<<EOF` by `<<'EOF'`.

Comment: Hmm, that solves it, thanks. Can you explain why it is so, and make it an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: It's syntax of [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells). Feel free to accept heemayl's answer.

Comment: what if i want the commands to be treated as text, but i still want variables ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quote `EOF` so that `bash` takes inputs literally:

```
cat <<'EOF' > what.txt
a=`echo $1 | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
b=`echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
EOF
```

Also start using `$()` for command substitution instead of old and problematic ``.